# Get location of libasan from gcc/clang

Tags: gcc, clang, address-sanitizer

When I compile with `-fsanitize=address`, GCC/Clang implicitly make use of an ASAN dynamic library which provides runtime support for ASAN. If your built library is dynamically loaded by another application, it is necessary to set `LD_PRELOAD` to include this dynamic library, so that it gets run at application start up time.

It is often not obvious which copy of `libasan.so` GCC/Clang expects to use, because there may be multiple copies of ASAN on your system (if you have multiple compilers installed.) Is there a reliable way to determine the location of the shared library you need to load?

Comment: Better late than never - I've updated my answer with something more suitable.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `-print-file-name` flag:

```
GCC_ASAN_PRELOAD=$(gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so)
CLANG_ASAN_PRELOAD=$(clang -print-file-name=libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so)
```

You could also extract libasan path from the library itself via `ldd`:

```
$ echo 'void foo() {}' | gcc -x c -fPIC -shared -fsanitize=address -
$ ldd a.out | grep libasan.so | awk '{print $3}'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4
```

Comment: `-print-file-name` didn't work for me under CentOS 7 or 8 with a non-default version of `gcc` because the file returned uses the [INPUT syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302402/) to reference another shared library, which apparently LD_PRELOAD doesn't support. The `ldd` script still worked though. Thanks!