# How to obtain the libasan.so path with Cmake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, address-sanitizer

I have a shared library in which the tests for a project are located. This is using [Cgreen](https://cgreen-devs.github.io/#_the_solution_the_cgreen_runner) as a test framework. This allows one to run all the tests using the cgreen runner as this:

```
cgreen-runner my-tests.so
```

I can do this from CMake pretty easy:

```
add_test(NAME mytest COMMAND ${CGREEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/my-tests.so)
```

The problem comes when I'm building `my-tests.so` with ASAN. Because it is a shared library built with ASAN loaded by an executable that's not built with ASAN I have to use `LD_PRELOAD` in order to load `libasan.so` (as covered by the [ASAN FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq)).

This is easy to do from the command line without needing to know where `libasan.so` is located, as long as you know the compiler used to compile the tests:

```
LD_PRELOAD=`gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so` cgreen-runner my-tests.so
```

I can set `LD_PRELOAD` from CMake by using `set_property`:

```
set_property(TEST mytest PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT "LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libasan.so")
```

Obviously, I don't want to have a hardcoded path there. Is there a way to obtain this path when configuring cmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply call the command from CMake:

```
execute_process(COMMAND gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBASAN_PATH
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

To catch failures you can pass a RESULT_VARIABLE and check if its value is equal to 0.

Comment: This could work. I think it is better to use `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` instead of `gcc` directly as someone may use `clang` and I'm not sure if things will work as intended in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are on a Fedora/RHEL system which uses [INPUT syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302402/), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386573/9759769, you can find the location with `cmake` like so:

```
set(__LOCATE_LIBASAN_CODE "int main() {return 0;}")
try_compile(
  STATUS SOURCE_FROM_VAR
  locateLibAsan.cpp __LOCATE_LIBASAN_CODE
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE __CMAKE_C_COMPILER_OUTPUT
  LINK_OPTIONS -fsanitize=address
  COPY_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locate_libasan NO_LOG)
if(NOT STATUS)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find location for libasan.so: ${__CMAKE_C_COMPILER_OUTPUT}")
else()
  execute_process(
    COMMAND ldd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locate_libasan
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LDD_OUTPUT
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    RESULT_VARIABLE STATUS)
  if(STATUS
     AND NOT
         STATUS
         EQUAL
         0)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find location for libasan.so: ${STATUS}")
  else()
    string(
      REGEX
      REPLACE ".*libasan\.so(\.[0-9]+) => ([a-zA-Z0-9\/\._-]+).*"
              "\\2"
              LIBASAN_LOCATION
              ${LDD_OUTPUT})
    message(STATUS "Found libasan.so: ${LIBASAN_LOCATION}")
    file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/.env" "LD_PRELOAD=${LIBASAN_LOCATION}")
  endif()
endif()
```